# Why is this query not correctly showing records associated with earliest dates?

Tags: php, mysql

My issue is that I have rows of varying dates being added constantly, so the first entry for a song in the table isn't necessarily the earliest occurrence, which is what I would like to display.

Played Table:

```
song_name        played_id        show_id
-------------------------------------------
A Song           0001             000a
Another Song     0002             000a
A Song           0003             000b
```

Shows Table:

```
show_id          date
-------------------------------------------
000a             2/2/2012
000b             1/1/2011
```

Desired result:

```
song_name        played_id         date
-------------------------------------------
A Song           0003              1/1/2011
Another Song     0002              2/2/2012
```

Current frustrating result:

```
song_name         played_id        date
-------------------------------------------
A Song            0001             2/2/2012
Another Song      0002             2/2/2012
```

Which comes from this query:

```
SELECT p.song_id, s.date AS date, p.song_name, p.show_id, p.set_order, p.played_id
FROM played p
INNER JOIN shows s
ON p.show_id = s.show_id
GROUP BY p.song_id
ORDER BY s.date ASC
```

When I add LIMIT 1 to the above query my result doesn't show the list of discrete song names but rather only shows one row.

I'm assuming I might need to be using a Sub Query since the GROUP BY is selecting the first occurrence of every song before ORDER BY gets a chance to look at all the dates, but I'm not sure. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    p.song_id,
    s.date,
    p.song_name,
    p.show_id,
    p.set_order,
    p.played_id
FROM
    played p
        INNER JOIN
    shows s ON p.show_id = s.show_id
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        p.song_id, MIN(s.date) DATE
    FROM
        played p
    INNER JOIN shows s ON p.show_id = s.show_id
    GROUP BY p.song_id) x ON p.song_id = x.song_id
        AND s.date = x.date;
```

It finds the earliest date for each song_id and then joins the result with the main join to find the required result.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!